# Misconeption about age of universe

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, big-bang

If we take the most distant quasars and galaxies from as in all directions we get a sphere of radius 13,7 billion light years. As we know they were there 13,7 billion years ago.This suggests the following: at the beginning (call it big bang) there was a sphere of 13,7 billion light years instead of a small point.Is this right?

Comment: That's not the radius of our observable universe FYI.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Misconceptions_about_its_size

Comment: I've removed some comments that should have been posted as answers.

Comment: Please see [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208) and this classic article by [Davis & Lineweaver](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/papers/SciAm_BigBang.pdf)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Putting 4 question marks at the end of your post does not make it into a question.

Comment: What Sammy said. You need to ask a clear question, or this question will get closed. I posted those links earlier in the hope that they'd help to clarify your misconceptions, and to prompt you to ask a focused question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok, I will try to formulate this in another form,but give me some time to change it....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104014/discussion-on-question-by-jbradvi9-misconeption-about-age-of-universe).